# How to distribute DIVs evenly to the content of the page with row direction from left to right without display:flex

Tags: html, css

I want divs to go from left to right but also to be evenly distributed in the content of the page with width: 100%;

Can this be done in CSS without using any JS or Display:Flex which actually allows you to do it with flex-direction .... but its not compatible with IE8 and IE9!

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
 text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}
#container:after {
 content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

div {
    width: 27%;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    background-color:lightblue;
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}

p { 
    maring:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:80px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div><p>A</p></div>
    <div><p>B</p></div>
    <div><p>C</p></div>
    <div><p>D</p></div>
    <div><p>E</p></div>
    <div><p>F</p></div>
    <div><p>G</p></div>
    <div><p>H</p></div>
</div>
```

Here is my code.

So basically ... The first div to be always on the left, the 3rd to be always on the right and the one in the middle. But everytime you add a new div it should be added from left to right. Not left > right > middle.

Already have the correct answer from @Sofiene DJEBALI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hei @Paulie_D , I did not mean to get around the requirement or abusing code blocks .. I was in a hurry to find an answer and actually this was my first post. I'll be carefull in the future when asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add float:left; to your div in your css :

```
    div {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    background-color:lightblue;
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/28/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sofiene DJEBALI . That solved my issue.